# Qt Main Window not loading its icon

Tags: qt, icons, qt-designer

I am using **Qt 4.8.4** and I have created a **QMainWindow** using **Qt Designer**, so my .ui file generates the corresponding ui_....h file. I have the corresponding .qrc with the correct icon inside, and I can see it when I preview my window using Qt Designer. At the end, when loading the application, **the window does not have any icon**, just the default Windows application icon.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to compile the project. Thus, I am not using any '.pro' file. Here is the code of the .vcxproj that compiles the Qt resource file:

```
<CustomBuild Include="dlgConnect.qrc">
  <FileType>Document</FileType>
  <AdditionalInputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">%(FullPath);%(AdditionalInputs)</AdditionalInputs>
  <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Rcc%27ing %(Identity)...</Message>
  <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">.\GeneratedFiles\qrc_%(Filename).cpp;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
  <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">"..\..\..\..\Software\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.4\bin\rcc.exe" -name "%(Filename)" -no-compress "%(FullPath)" -o .\GeneratedFiles\qrc_%(Filename).cpp</Command>
  <AdditionalInputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">%(FullPath);%(AdditionalInputs)</AdditionalInputs>
  <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Rcc%27ing %(Identity)...</Message>
  <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">.\GeneratedFiles\qrc_%(Filename).cpp;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
  <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">"..\..\..\..\Software\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.4\bin\rcc.exe" -name "%(Filename)" -no-compress "%(FullPath)" -o .\GeneratedFiles\qrc_%(Filename).cpp</Command>
</CustomBuild>
```

It seems to be correct but I have no successful result.

Does anybody experienced the same?

Cheers,

Comment: Did you add a Windows resource file with the icon as being the first item? It used to be necessary with older Qt versions, I'm not sure it's still needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this in your **.pro** file

```
RC_FILE += Icon.rc
```

and you need this in your **Icon.rc** file

```
IDI_ICON1   ICON   DISCARDABLE   "./MyIcon.ico"
```

and you need the **MyIcon.ico** icon file.

Comment: Hi HWende, thanks for your help. I am not using .pro files since I am compiling the project using Visual Studio 2010. Please see my edited question for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately then I can't help you. But please consider using the QtCreator, it's really great for creating Qt programs.